# Where is the syntax error in my VHDL code?

Tags: syntax, vhdl, hardware, fpga, intel-fpga

I am writing a square wave generator in vhdl, I was just confused why I am getting a syntax error in my LUT declaration (line 21). I have spent hours trying to find my mistake by commenting out certian snippets and including different things, but it is always the same error.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity highlow_square is
   PORT ( clk    : in  STD_LOGIC; -- clock to be divided
           reset  : in  STD_LOGIC; -- active-high reset
           enable : in  STD_LOGIC; -- active-high enable
           Ampselect : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);

                                   -- useful to enable another device, like to slow down a counter
           value  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (9 downto 0) -- outputs the current_count value, if needed
         );
end highlow_square;

architecture Behavioral of highlow_square is
signal duty_cycle_sig : std_logic_vector (9 downto 0);
signal current_count : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
signal check : integer := 0;  
type array_1d is array (0 to 15) of integer;
constant DutyCycle_LUT : array_1d := (‭ 
(   1023    )   ,
(   960 )   ,
(   897 )   ,
(   834 )   ,
(   771 )   ,
(   708 )   ,
(   645 )   ,
(   582 )   ,
(   519 )   ,
(   456 )   ,
(   393 )   ,
(   330 )   ,
(   267 )   ,
(   204 )   ,
(   141 )   ,
(   78      )       
);


begin

duty_cycle_sig <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(DutyCycle_LUT(to_integer(unsigned(Ampselect))),duty_cycle_sig'length));


   count: process(clk,reset,check,enable)

    begin 
       if (reset = '1') then 
          current_count <= "0000000000" ;

       elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then 
        if(enable = '1') then
            if(check = 0) then
                if(current_count < "1111111110") then
                current_count <= current_count + "10";
                value <= duty_cycle_sig;
                end if;

                if(current_count = "1111111100") then
                check <= 1;
                end if;

            else
                if(current_count > "000000000") then
                current_count <= current_count - "10";
                value <= "0000000000";
                end if;

                if(current_count = "0000000010") then
                check <= 0;
                end if;


        end if;
    end if;
    end if;      
  end process;



END Behavioral;
```

I get the following error

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at highlow_square.vhdl(21) near text 
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at highlow_square.vhdl(21) near text "";  expecting ")", or ","
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at highlow_square.vhdl(21) near text ­
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at highlow_square.vhdl(47) near text ")";  expecting ":", or ","
```

I do not know where I am making the error in my LUT declaration or before it. Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: `ghdl -a highlow_square.vhdl
highlow_square.vhdl:21:40:error: control character that is not CR, LF, FF, HT or VT is not allowed highlow_square.vhdl:21:41:error: character '�' can only be used in strings or comments ghdl:error: compilation error` You have what appears to be a multibyte character in line 21 `array_1d := (\U+202D`, while VHDL only supports ISO-8859-1.  You can usually set the character set an editor uses, sometimes by file type or extension. Perhaps `current_count` should be type `unsigned`?

Comment: Whether the non Latin 1 character go in there by typing or cut and paste it's a typographic error.

Comment: or try without the () around the integers...

Comment: Thanks! I ended up rewriting the entire LUT from scratch and it compiled!

Comment: No, it's really an embedded [multibtype character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEiUU.jpg). rewriting the line, changing `current_count` to type `unsigned` and the design description analyzes and elaborates (compiles). The constant's locally static subtype and number of integers in the value expression match. An expression surrounded by parentheses is only valid if it's also valid without the parentheses.  Extra parentheses are visual noise unless required by syntax.